# address parsing and validation technique required for Australia zone with regex

Tags: java, php, javascript

We need to implement the validation for the following field

**Street Address/ Business Address**

Conditions which needs to be taken care are as below

Post office box, private bag NOT acceptable as address. The address field should not start with the following:

**NOTE:** ***^ = space***

```
G^P^O    
GPO^    
G.P.O    
GPO.    
G.P.O. Box

P^O    
P.O    
PO^    
PO.    
P.O.    
P.O.B    
POBOX    
POST BOX    
POST OFFICE BOX    
P / O Box    
P/O Box    
P O Box    
P.O. Box

BOX^    
BOX.    
Private Bag^    
Private Bag.    
Locked Bag
```

This list needs to be configurable to allow for additional rules to be included at a later date. There is no need to validate for upper/lower case

Can you suggest me this kind of validation can be better implement using Javascript or Java?

1. if I use Java, is it advisable to use Regex class
2. If Javascript, what should be my way

Kindly share your sample code if you have any

I am checking if we use of Regex would be helpful in doing this?

ps:  Since this project cant use any google or yahoo api or any other paid APIs to parse the street address.

Comment: why did you tag this question with a 'php' tag? Does php bear any significance here?

Comment: I doubt there's one regex that covers all those scenarios. Best if you use multiple matches for one or few conditions and do nested if-statements instead.

Comment: I am using PHP as well in the development

Comment: Do you want to do this on the server or client side? I would Javascript on the client side, and php on the server side (if that is what you are using on the server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use regexp in that case. Instead I'd put all "stop words" in a file, read it into a set and use a loop to verify:

```
public static boolean isValid(String address) {
  Set<String> stopWords = getSet();  // some magic to get the loaded set
  for (String stopWord:stopWords) {
    if (address.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(stopWord.toLowerCase())) {
       return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Big advantage: the stop words are maintained in a file and not *compiled* into some regular expression that no one will understand next week and later.

Answer (score 0):

Not a regex guru my self, so i my answer will be the long way of doing it.

you can include the list of possible values in a regex:

```
/(G\sP\sO)|(GPO\s)|(G\.P\.O)|(G\.P\.O\.\sBox)| .... and so one
```

I don't think it's the most efficient way of solving the problem but it will still work.